# Running ScalaTest in IntelliJ removes everything but idea_rt.jar from classpath

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

I am trying to run a ScalaTest test case from IntelliJ

I specify the class path to use in the run/debug configuration dialogue and this appears to work ok.

However, if I try to interrogate this classpath using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` 
I only get the `idea_rt.jar`

This wouldn't be a problem except I am trying to do this inside an Integration test:

```
val execArgs = Array("java", 
    "-classpath", 
    System.getProperty("java.class.path"), 
    mainClass, 
    args)

val process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(execArgs)
```

And, of course, my `mainClass` is not found.

My config.

- scalatest_2.9.2-1.8.RC1
- IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3
- scala-library-2.9.2
- scala plugin version 0.5.977

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit `bin/idea.properties` or `Info.plist` if you are on Mac, set this to `true`:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configure if a special launcher should be used when running processes from within IDE.
# Using Launcher enables "soft exit" and "thread dump" features
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.no.launcher=true
```

Comment: Editing Info.plist would break the app signature. Surely there is an external file which they read as well. (I tried putting it in as a -D in idea.vmoptions and was surprised that it didn't work.)